# How to display particular value via filter?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-filter, angular2-directives

I have such data in my app:

```
birthdayGreetings:Array<any> = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        date: new Date(1994, 3, 19),
        greeting: 'Happy Birthday, John! Good luck!',
        displayName: false
    }
];
```

I need to show only NAME when it's date is on this week, so I do this:

```
export class ThisWeekPipe {

transform(myArr) {

    var result =  myArr.filter(
        item => {
            var day = item.date.getDate();
            if(day >= 4 && day <= 10) {
                item.displayName = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    );

    return result;
  }
}
```

But I always get the same result (just elements of array which are ok with that filter)

Here is html:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="#manBirthday of birthdayGreetings | thisWeekPipe">
          {{ manBirthday }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

How can I do that in a right way? Thank you

Comment: You could use map along with filter.  `myArr.filter(...).map(i => return i.name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update your pipe this way:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'thisWeekPipe'
})
export class ThisWeekPipe {
  transform(myArr) {
    return myArr.filter(item => {
      var day = item.date.getDate();
      return (day >= 4 && day <= 10);
    }).map(item => item.name);
  }
}
```

You first filter the list to get only elements that match to the date criteria and then only use the `name` property. This way you only get a list of name to display in an `ngFor` loop.

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/6VHtFp4zvvMdm3rXbFOP?p=preview.

Comment: And what should I do if I need to return a greeting property whether the date of birth is today in a addition to that? Should I add one more map? Thank you